# Is it enough in reCaptcha3 to automatically bind the challenge to a button or is there more to do?

Tags: recaptcha-v3

I am writing about this documentation:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

I implemented everything shown in the chapter
"Automatically bind the challenge to a button"
but I keep on getting spam through my form.

I understood, that this should work and that the following chapters on this page are optional. Am I wrong? What is the minimum configuration?

My solution is still in ASP.net, but I only applied changes to the client side, as described in the forementioned chapter. As a consequence, the reCaptcha logo appears and sais that my form is being protected:

https://www.premieraupair.org/Contact

These are the steps I followed:

[image: Automatically bind the challenge to a button]